# Disable VoLTE, while still using LTE - To force Jio4gVoice to work

Tags: 4g, nexus-5x, 9.0-pie

I have a Nexus 5X running an unofficial Pie build (https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/development/rom-android-source-project-t3827122)

VoLTE does not work (no incoming or outgoing calls), but data over LTE works. So the Jio4gVoice app should be able to receive calls (over data, meant for non-VoLTE phones). But the problem is that this app detects that the phone is VoLTE compatible and simply refuses to connect.

PS: The phone supports VoLTE, I've used it before, but this particular ROM doesn't.

I'm looking for a way to disable VoLTE so that the app can work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is wait in case nexus annouces its support for android pie then upgrade. As of now degrade to previous version of android.

Note: You can try some more ROMs, so that you can enjoy VoLTE.

Comment: Nexus 5X has completed its 2 year support period and will never receive Pie. And there are only 2 ROMs based on Pie and both have this problem.